# How to cancel a background task in windows 8.1 using javascript

Tags: windows-8, background, winjs, windows-8.1

I am building a windows 8 metro app using javascript and html5. I want to know following things.

1. How can I cancel the current instance of any running background task.
2. What are the possible conditions when system automatically cancels background task.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript background tasks are executed in web workers, so just use `close()` within running background task to end it when ever you want. If you want to do this from your app code, check out following MSDN sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj160500.aspx.

There are many conditions when system may cancel your task, but that depends how you registered it (is it lock screen task etc). In normal conditions each background tasks has 1s CPU quota and 7.5 MB daily data quota. You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977046.aspx